# Spinor representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ on Weyl Spinors.

Tags: representation-theory, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

Let $Cl(1,3)$ be the Clifford algebra for $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^4$ equipped with a Minkowski scalar product of signature $(-,+,+,+)$. The complexification of the Clifford algebra is $\text{End}(\mathbb{C}^4)$, and there is thus a faithful representation of $Cl(1,3)$ on $\mathbb{C}^4$ given by the gamma block matrices:

\begin{align*}
            \Gamma_0=&\begin{pmatrix}
            0&iI_2\\
            iI_2&0
        \end{pmatrix}\\
        \Gamma_i=&\begin{pmatrix}
            0&i\sigma_i\\
            -i\sigma_i&0
        \end{pmatrix}\text{ for all }i=1,2,3
\end{align*}
here $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli spin matrices.

There is a chirality element given by:
\begin{align*}
        \Gamma_5=&-i^3\Gamma_0\Gamma_1\Gamma_2\Gamma_3\\
        =&\begin{pmatrix}
            -I_2&0\\
            0&I_2
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}
Which splits the space into a direct sum $\mathbb{C}^2\oplus\mathbb{C}^2$ corresponding to the eigenspaces of $\Gamma_5$. These spaces are called right (negative) and left (positive) handed Weyl spinors.

I am trying to figure out the representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}^2\oplus \mathbb{C}^2$ induced by the above faithful representation, but I am getting pretty confused.

First note that $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is the spin group $Spin^+(1,3)$, where $Spin^+(1,3)$ is the subgroup of invertible Clifford elements generated by elements of the form:

$$v_1\cdots v_{2q}$$

where an even number of $\langle v_i,v_i\rangle=1$ and even amount satisfy $\langle v_i,v_i\rangle=-1$. It follows that the induced representation $\kappa$ on any element of $Spin^+(1,3)$ is found by writing:

$$v_j= v_j^{i_j}e_{i_j}$$

where there is an implied sum over $i_j$ is implied, and then taking:

$$\kappa(v_1\cdots v_{2q})=v_{1}^{i_1}\cdots v_{2q}^{i_{2q}}\Gamma_{i_1}\cdots \Gamma_{i_{2q}}$$

In particular, $e_ie_j\in Spin^+(1,3)$ for $0<i\leq j\leq 3$. However, I calculate:

$$\Gamma_i\Gamma_j=\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_i\sigma_j&0\\
0&\sigma_i\sigma_j
\end{pmatrix}$$
Now each pauli spin matrix satisfies $\det(\sigma_i)=-1$, so each block matrix lies in $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. To me this seems to suggest that $\kappa$ is the direct sum of the standard representation on $\mathbb{C}^2$, however I know that this shouldn't be true. Some argument from physics, which I don't follow, seem to suggest that that the representation should be the direct sum of the standard representation and the induced conjugate representation, but I can't see why.

One thing I thought was that it could be that the pauli matrices are a little to nice to figure what the actual representation is. But, I don't really know what else to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it seems that I can't find a succinct answer to this question.

Comment: Not sure whether it helps, but those elements of $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ that you wrote down are in its subgroup $SU_2$.

Comment: I agree, meaning if one rep is the standard one, and the other is conjugate dual rep, then I wouldn’t see it.

Comment: There are two non-equivalent representations of $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ on $\Bbb{C}^2$.  One is the standard one $A\cdot v = Av$.  The other is $A\cdot v = ((A^{-1})^*) v$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Ok but how do I see that’s what happening here. Also is the star conjugate transpose?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, star is conjugate transpose.  I know from Physics that these are the two representations associated with left or right chiral spinors.  Physicists usually define this using a basis, not the way I wrote it.  I don't know how to see the relation to Clifford algebra.  Notice that the automorphism of $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ given by $A\mapsto (A^{-1})^*$ is the identity on $SU(2)$.

Comment: @JohnDoe I understand that. What I am asking is how do I see that the representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ on the space of left and right chiral spinors splits into a direct sum of representations of the standard representation and the $(A^{-1})^*$ representation.